# Why /bin/systemctl?

Tags: systemd, fhs

According to the system experts, the correct location of `systemctl` is `/usr/bin/systemctl`:

https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2019-August/043224.html

Why does Ubuntu use `/bin/systemctl`?

Related: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/

Comment: To me it makes more sense the way Ubuntu does it. But you would have to ask the developers to get the correct answer.

Comment: Since Ubuntu is Debian-based, see the [Debian page on the topic](https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge). The answer to "why" seems simple: Limited Debian Developer interest in the proposal.

Comment: it should be /sbin/systemctl or /usr/sbin/systemctl :=)

Comment: @Rinzwind `systemctl status foo-service` should be available to all users. This means `sbin` is the wrong place.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix why "you would have to ask..."? See my first link. I did it. I asked them yesterday.

Comment: @guettli ah but users should not be allowed to mess with my servers >:)

Comment: @Rinzwind I want `systemctl status foo-service` to work as non-root user. This makes check-scripts easier. At least in my environment most checking gets done as non-root user.

Answer (score 3):

So booting into a system with a separate `/usr` partition is not supported by systemd. More specifically, switching root to a system where `/usr` is not yet mounted is not supported, in such systems, the initramfs should mount both `/` *and* `/usr` before switching root.

Having said that, the configuration with a separate `/usr` mostly worked in systemd systems, and it used to work almost well in older versions of systemd, before they officially declared it unsupported and started rejecting fixes for those setups.

(You've already referred to [The Case for the `/usr` Merge](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/), so you can read more there on the inherent problems with those setups and motivations for the merge as a fix.)

Since historically supporting systems with separate `/usr` was necessary to some extent, a decision had to be made of whether to put `systemctl` under `/usr` or outside it. The main question to answer in this context is: what happens if `/usr` fails to mount and you need to fix your system into booting again? If `systemctl` was under `/usr`, it wouldn't be available, while if it's in `/bin`, you'll have it around. Given you're likely to be starting, stopping and checking status of services while trying to fix your system, shipping it in the root partition makes sense.

But, again, merging `/usr` is the real solution for this, since then these points are all moot. If `/usr` fails to mount you're still on an initramfs and can use the tools inside there for fixing it. All modern distributions are switching to a merged `/usr`, so this solution should be around most Linux setups real soon now.